# How do I pass kwargs to pydantic validator

Tags: python-3.x, validation, python-dataclasses, pydantic

I'm trying to write [`pydantic` validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/), but I can't seem to understand how to make use of the `kwargs` argument that is mentioned in the docs.  I would like to pass conditional parameters for validation.  Here's a toy example:

```
from pydantic import validator
import pydantic.dataclasses as pyd_dc


@pyd_dc.dataclass
class Point_t:
    x: int = 0
    y: int = 1

    @validator("y")
    def quadrant(cls, val, values, **kwargs):
        pt = x, y = values.get("x", None), val
        if x is None:
            raise ValueError(f"invalid point: {x}, {y}")

        signs = kwargs.get("signs", None)
        if signs is None:
            raise ValueError("'signs' parameter missing")

        if all(c * s >= 0 for c, s in zip(pt, signs) if s != 0):
            return val

        raise ValueError(f"{pt} not in quadrant: {signs}")
```

This doesn't seem to work, instantiating a `Point_t` object leads to a validation error:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Point_t
y
  'signs' parameter missing (type=value_error)
```

How do I pass on the `signs` parameter in the above example?  If there's no way, what's the point of allowing for `**kwargs`?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Because [Pydantic.validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) are **class methods** here.

### what's the point of allowing for **kwargs?

Since validators are “class methods”,and full signature here is equal to
`(cls, value, *, values, config, field)`

In other word, your `def quadrant(..., **kwargs):` is **euqal** to `config, field`

### How do I pass kwargs to pydantic validator

1) Create custom [config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/) and read from config

2) Fields hack

```py
class Point_t:
    signs = dict
    x: int = 0

    def quadrant(cls, val, values, **kwargs):
        signs = values[signs]
        if signs is None:
            raise ValueError("'signs' parameter missing")

        if all(c * s >= 0 for c, s in zip(pt, signs) if s != 0):
            return val
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using `Config` on the pydantic model. This is especially relevant when creating reusable validators.

```
from pydantic import validator
import pydantic.dataclasses as pyd_dc


def name_must_match(cls, v: str) -> str:
    """
    Throw an error if the provided value does not match
    the class name (`cls.Config.name`)

    Note: for this validator to work, provided pydantic model (`cls`)
    must have a Config attribute, with a `name` attribute.
    """
    if v != cls.Config.name:
        raise ValueError('value does not equal class name')
    return v

# Now to use the validator

@pyd_dc.dataclass
class Point:
    """Some pydantic model"""

    class Config:
        """Store extra info here"""
        name = 'foo'

    # define your fields
    name: str = 'foo'
    x: int = 0
    y: int = 1
    
    # Fields with underscores can be hidden from json encoder
    _name =  validator('name',
                        allow_reuse=True,
                        pre=True,
                        always=True
                        )(name_must_match)

# To test it out
>> Point(name='foo', x=1, y=2)
Point(name='foo', x=1, y=2)

>> Point(name='bar', x=3, y=4)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Point
name
  value does not equal class name (type=value_error)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but `Config` is still static. In your example you can't have two points  with different allowed names.  My goal with this effort was to establish a validation pattern that which can then be configured and reused for specific cases.

Comment: Understood. Would passing values into initialization of the class be sufficient? or, are you explicitly looking for something which behaves more as a method? @suvayu

Comment: I am expecting something like this: context 1 `Point(data1, config1)` and in context 2 `Point(data2, config2)`. The validation pattern is identical between the two contexts, but configured differently (in this toy example, I get to choose the allowed quadrant out of the 4 possibilities).  In my actual use, I generate the validation classes dynamically, so this example doesn't correspond to it exactly.

Comment: I see. You could define Config parameters and pass them around (as demonstrated here [create a base schema extra and modify within each instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68472497/16309709) --> but that's probably overkill for what you want. @suvayu

Comment: A hacky type of solution could be to create a new field explicitly for this validation method. Ex: `_name: str = 'foo'` --> then, in your validator, you can access this value from this list of values. If this sounds relevant, let me know and I'll modify my answer to reflect this @suvayu

Comment: All these alternatives are way too complicated for dynamic code generation (my actual use case, as mentioned in the above comment).  Also, creating a new field mixes config with data, which is not ideal for me.  Since I asked the question, I have worked around the issue by using closures.  I create the validator functions before generating the models, it's not ideal, but probably the least complicated way to do it.

Comment: Good approach. And I agree, my provided solution is indeed complicated. Curious to see what other solutions are provided. @suvayu

Comment: You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/calliope-project/typedconfig/blob/master/typedconfig/factory.py); it's not quite finalised. Pydantic internals are not exactly friendly to this kind of code generation, so in a few places my implementation relies on some "magic" (see comments in the `make_validator` function).

Comment: Clever work. Perhaps consider opening an issue on the pydantic project? https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/contributing/

Comment: Thanks, I have considered that, I think they are more focused on features like (de)serialisation, interfacing with APIs, DB models, etc.  Ideally I would prefer something much more lightweight, and have all these advanced features as plugins/modules.  I'll re-evaluate depending on my usability experience with my current implementation.

Comment: Such is the way of open source development.

Comment: @suvayu I looked into the link you posted but was not able to understand what was happening there. I am also looking to something similar to what you were looking. Can you guide me here? Thank you

Comment: @sin.hyp.a I would advise against using Pydantic like this. It's just not written with this kind of use in mind. Currently many of Pydantic internals are being rewritten in Rust (if I'm not mistaken), so quite possibly my hack (which is what it is, since it relies on undocumented behaviour) will stop working.  Maybe a better solution would be to use `attrs` for code generation, and use Pydantic separately.