# Pydantic models good practice in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am building a REST API with FastAPI and I really like the tool, especially the integration with Pydantic and OpenAPI.

For instance I can write the model taken by an endpoint as

```py
class Model(BaseModel):
    field1: str = Field(default=...)
    field2: int = Field(default=...)
    field3: List[int] = Field(default=...)
    field4: float = Field(default=...)
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                'field1': 'example 1',
                'field2': 1,
                'field3': [1, 2],
                'field4': 1.3,
            }
        }
```

I find however that I have quite some repetitions in my code as for example if I want to create another class inheriting from `Model` that adds another field `field5`, I would need to re-write the `Config` class in order to define the new example.

Is there a good way of doing this? For example, is there any tool that allows you to define the fields with all the properties and example and then creating the class `Model` from a definition of what it requires to include?

Or any other pattern that is better suited for this is also welcome.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a base schema extra and modify within each instantiation:

```
base_schema_extra = {
    "example": {
        'field1': 'example 1',
        'field2': 1,
        'field3': [1, 2],
        'field4': 1.3,
    }
}

class Model(BaseModel):
    field1: str = Field(default=...)
    field2: int = Field(default=...)
    field3: List[int] = Field(default=...)
    field4: float = Field(default=...)

    class Config:
        schema_extra = base_schema_extra


class Model2(BaseModel):
    field1: str = Field(default=...)
    field2: int = Field(default=...)
    field3: List[int] = Field(default=...)
    field4: float = Field(default=...)
    field5: bool = Field(default=...)

    class Config:
        schema_extra = dict(**base_schema_extra, **{'field5': True})
```

You can also inherit classes using the following:

```
class Model3(Model2):
    field6: bool = Field(default=...)

    class Config(Model.Config):
        schema_extra = dict(**Model.Config.schema_extra, **{'field6': False})
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am doing. I still feel there should be a better way of doing this

Comment: Did you see my 3rd suggestion? (`Model3`) @GZZ --> and unfortunately, this appears to be a challenge in creating pydantic models which inherit multiple models. Probably to do with [diamond inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199975/resolving-diamond-inheritance-within-python-classes) conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Declare another class that inherits from Base `Model` class. Add another field. The `Config` will remain the same but an extra example field.

```
class ChildModel(Model):
    field5: str = Field(default=...)
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                'field1': 'example 1',
                'field2': 1,
                'field3': [1, 2],
                'field4': 1.3,
                'field5': 'foo'
            }
        }
```

It will work, no issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this is exactly what I was referring to in my post. You had to re-define the example for all the fields.